# How to show different results through one loop?

Tags: php, loops

I have a loop for catalog display results:

```
{foreach $products as $p}
  <div class="product_list">
    <img src={$p.pic}>
    <h2>Product {$p.name}</h2>
{/foreach}
```

But results looks the same for Product 1, Product 2, Product 3.

How to do a different view for its through this loop, for example:
The Product 1 is displayed with a large picture, and Product 2 and 3 with small.

Something like this in result:
[Catalog with different conditions for next element in the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfjeX.jpg)

Comment: What syntax is that, smarty?

Comment: Use an if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's Smarty v3, then the foreach (and other loops) provide a property that can be checked - such as [`@first`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.first)

```
{* show table header at first iteration *}
<table>
{foreach $items as $i}
  {if $i@first}
    <tr>
      <th>key</td>
      <th>name</td>
    </tr>
  {/if}
  <tr>
    <td>{$i@key}</td>
    <td>{$i.name}</td>
  </tr>
{/foreach}
</table>
```

In your instance, you could change the css class to allow for a larger image:

```
<img src="{$p.pic}" class="{if $i@first}large-pic{else}small-pic{/if}">
```

Or, you can wrap the `img` tag with a div with an ID or class, or other method to allow to show a larger image for only the first loop.

Comment: Neat, I've been using V3 for ages but didn't know about the @ syntax to reference the current iteration meta.